# How can I count distinct elements with Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I was wondering if Memgraph supports something like `COUNT(DISTINCT x)` and if not how can I achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Memgraph 2.5.0 there is no longer need for constructions like `WITH DISTINCT n.prop as distinct_prop RETURN COUNT(distinct_prop)`. You can use `RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT n.prop)` instead.